# How to handle async router in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, routes, router

With Vue 3 router actions have gone async. Previously when you called `push` or `replace`, the change was instant, but that's not the case anymore.

```js
console.log(route.name) // Home
router.push({ name: "About" })
console.log(route.name) // Home
```

This can easily be handled by using await.

```js
console.log(route.name) // Home
await router.push({ name: "About" })
console.log(route.name) // About
```

While this seems like a clean solution, it presents other problems. Let's say you have 2 unrelated components and they both call replace at appx. the same time to add a query to url.

```js
// Component 1
router.replace({
  query: {
    ...route.query,
    query1: "foo"
  }
})

// Component 2
router.replace({
  query: {
    ...route.query,
    query2: "bar"
  }
})
```

Route should now have both query1 and query2. But due to async routing if both actions are called at the same, route change from first `replace` will not yet be applied when the second `replace` is called. Result will be route with only one query, which one is determined by which `replace` was the last one to be called.

```js
// expected
{
  name: "...",
  query: {
    query1: "foo",
    query2: "bar"
  }
}

// result
{
  name: "...",
  query: {
    query2: "bar"
  }
}
```

As these actions are happening at different locations it's not possible to await one change before calling another without relocating implementation, which could be very impractical.

How do you handle this? And does anybody know why has Vue Router changed it's implementation? Seems like it was better before.

Comment: It cannot be generalized like. It's unknown why route.push can be performed concurrently and it depends on your case how this needs to be solved. Consider explaining it further. "And does anybody know why has Vue Router changed it's implementation" - such issues like this one are solved in official repo, could be a regression that may or may not be known, the users who are aware of it are more likely to be found there, not in random discussions. On the other hand, it makes sense for it to work like that, otherwise you would be unable to overridde query instead of merging it if necessary

Comment: "As these actions are happening at different locations it's not possible to await one change before calling another without relocating implementation" - why would it matter which was first or second?  Just await them individually and your route will end up with both because the first push would be applied and then the second would pick up the correct `route.query` and add to it.

Comment: i have the same problem